# How to return value from coroutine in viewmodelScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, coroutine, android-viewmodel

I am using `Room` and I need to return `id` to `Fragment` which is returned when `insert()`.

However, But I couldn't return the value from viewModelScope.

I saw other similar questions, but the answer was to return `LiveData`.

But I don't need `LiveData`. I just want to return values ​​of type Long.

How can I do it?

---

**Repo**

```
class WorkoutListRepository(private val dao: WorkoutDao) {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    suspend fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) : Long {
        ...
        return dao.insertDailyLog(data)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class WorkoutListViewModel(
    private val repository: WorkoutListRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    
    ...
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) : Long {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@launch repository.createDailyLog(part) // can't return
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class WorkoutListTabPagerFragment : Fragment(), WorkoutListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
   ...
 
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentWorkoutListTabPagerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

            ...
        return binding.root
    }
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onItemClick(workout: String) {
        when(PageState.curPageState) {
            is PageState.startWorkout -> {
                val id = vm.createDailyLog(part)
                    ...
            }
            is PageState.addWorkout -> //TODO:
            is PageState.editWorkout -> //TODO:
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't need LiveData

You do. You need some kind of observable data holder because the code inside `launch` is asynchronous. It doesn't run immediately. It is only kind of scheduled for execution. `launch` function, on the other hand, returns immediately, i.e. your `createDailyLog` function in ViewModel returns before the call to `repository.createDailyLog(part)` is made. So you can't return a value synchronously from an asynchronous method.

You could either use `LiveData` or Kotlin's `StateFlow` to send this data to the Fragment. Your fragment will observe changes to that state and respond accordingly. I suggest using `StateFlow` here. The code will look somewhat like this:

```kotlin
// ViewModel
class WorkoutListViewModel(
    private val repository: WorkoutListRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    

    private val _logIdFlow = MutableStateFlow<Long?>(null)
    val logIdFlow = _logIdFlow.asStateFlow()
    ...
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) : Long {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _logIdFlow.value = repository.createDailyLog(part)
        }
    }
}

// Fragment
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentWorkoutListTabPagerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        ...

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.logIdFlow.collect { logId ->
                if(logId != null) {
                    // Do whatever you want with the log Id
                }
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

An alternate solution can be to use Kotlin `Channel` and send data through that `Channel`.

If you just need a quick, short solution, you can call the repository function from the Fragment's lifecycle scope directly, like this:

```kotlin
// ViewModel
suspend fun createDailyLog(part: BodyPart) : Long {
    return repository.createDailyLog(part)
}

//Fragment
override fun onItemClick(workout: String) {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        when(PageState.curPageState) {
            is PageState.startWorkout -> {
                val id = vm.createDailyLog(part) // This will now work
                    ...
            }
            is PageState.addWorkout -> //TODO:
            is PageState.editWorkout -> //TODO:
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem with this solution is that, now db operation is tied to fragment's lifecycle. So if there is any event which destroy's fragment's lifecycle (like a config change), the operation will be cancelled. This shouldn't be that big of an issue here as your db operation will only take a few milliseconds. But the first option of using a `StateFlow` or `Channel` to send data to Fragment/Activity is a more general and recommended way. You can go with whichever option you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me ask you a question.

**1.** I don't know what is the difference between `inside launch` and `launch function` you mentioned..

**2.** You said `your createDailyLog function in ViewModel returns before the call to repository.createDailyLog(part) is made.` But at least as far as I know, when the `suspend function` is executed, the `coroutine` that called the `suspend function` is paused. Then, shouldn't the coroutine of `ViewModel's createDailyLog()` be stopped when `Repo's createDailyLog()` is executed?

Comment: Yes, coroutine inside `launch {}` waits for `createDailyLog()` to finish. However, `launch {}` itself, as its name suggests, launches the code inside it asynchronously, in the background.